# How can i restart a game with a button in wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

First of all i am sorry about the grammer mistakes in my English.. it's not my native language..

This is the code:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
from random import randint

OPTIONS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "DEL", 0, "SEND"]
# these are the events' IDs sent to a function when you click a button.
# the OPTIONS_ID is in the same order of OPTIONS.

OPTIONS_ID = [-31984,-31983,-31982,-31981,-31980,-31979, -31978, -31977, -31976, -31975, -31974, -31973]  # the built in wxpython IDs for the buttons


GAME_POSITION = (400, 100)
GAME_SIZE = [900, 600]

def RandomNum():
    count = 5
    while count > 4:
        num = randint(1000, 9999)
        digits = str(num)
        count = 0
        for digit in digits:
            for digit2 in digits:
                if digit == digit2:
                    count = count + 1
    return digits

def message_dialog(message, caption, style=wx.OK, position=GAME_POSITION):
    if message != "":  # making sure not to execute a message if its empety
        message = wx.MessageDialog(None, message, caption, style, position)
        answer = message.ShowModal()
        message.Destroy()
        return answer
    else:
        return -1

class Frame(wx.Frame):  # class for all the frames in our game.

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.fdf = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(275, 75), pos=(520, 20))
            self.count = 0
            self.turnsCounter = 0
            self.numbers = RandomNum()
            self.bulls = 0
            self.cows = 0
            self.counter_of_turns = 0
            self.check = False

            self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self.panel, pos = (85, 150), size=(323, 212))
            self.grid.CreateGrid(10, 3)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
            for i in range(10):
                for j in range(4):
                    self.grid.SetReadOnly(i, j)
            self.grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "guess")
            self.grid.SetColLabelValue(1, "cows")
            self.grid.SetColLabelValue(2, "bulls")



    # this function creates a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
    def write(self, panel, txt, pos, size=20, font_family=wx.SWISS, font_style = wx.NORMAL,font_weight = wx.BOLD, underline = False):
        # create a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
        your_txt = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, txt, pos)
        your_txt.SetFont(wx.Font(size,font_family,font_style,font_weight,underline))
    # same as above, just for a button.
    def create_button(self, panel, txt, position, width, height):
        Size = wx.Size(width, height)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, txt, position, Size)
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.border.Add(self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: self.OnButton(evt), self.button)
    def disable_button(self, panel, txt, position, width, height):
        Size = wx.Size(width, height)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, txt, position, Size)
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.border.Add(self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: self.OnButton(evt), self.button)
        self.button.Disable()

    def count_bulls(self, txtctrl, seria):
        for i in range(4):
            if seria[i] == txtctrl[i]:
                self.bulls += 1
        replacement = self.bulls
        self.bulls = 0
        return replacement

    def count_cows(self, txtctrl, seria):
        for i in range(4):
            if seria[i] != txtctrl[i] and seria[i] in txtctrl:
                self.cows += 1
        replacement = self.cows
        self.cows = 0
        return replacement


    def OnButton(self, event):
        print repr(event.Id) + ","
        if event.Id in OPTIONS_ID:  # if indeed an option button was pressed
            exited = -1  # exited is 5100 if the user exited his dialog box
            # assigning the events to the button.
            for i in range(12):
                if event.Id != -31975 and event.Id != -31973 and event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[i]:
                    self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[i]))
                    self.count += 1
            if event.Id == -31973:
                self.counter_of_turns += 1
                print self.numbers
                print self.fdf.GetValue()
                cows = self.count_cows(self.fdf.GetValue(), self.numbers)
                bulls = self.count_bulls(self.fdf.GetValue(), self.numbers)
                self.grid.SetCellValue(self.turnsCounter,0, self.fdf.GetValue())
                self.grid.SetCellValue(self.turnsCounter, 1, str(cows))
                self.grid.SetCellValue(self.turnsCounter, 2, str(bulls))
                self.fdf.Clear()
                self.count = 0
                if self.turnsCounter < 9:
                    self.turnsCounter += 1
                if bulls == 4:
                    self.check = True
                    message_dialog("Well done! you won this game..", "You won!")
            if event.Id == -31975:
                if self.count > 0:
                    self.count -= 1
                self.fdf.Remove(self.fdf.GetLastPosition()-1, self.fdf.GetLastPosition())
            if self.count == 4:
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                        try:
                            int(child.GetLabel())
                        except ValueError:
                            if child.GetLabel() == "SEND":
                                child.Enable()
                        else:
                            child.Disable()
            elif self.check == False:
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if child.GetLabel() != "SEND":
                        child.Enable()
                    else:
                        child.Disable()
                    if self.count == 0:
                        if child.GetLabel() == "DEL":
                            child.Disable()
            else:
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                        child.Disable()
            for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                    if child.GetLabel() in self.fdf.GetValue():
                        child.Disable()
            if self.counter_of_turns == 10:
                message_dialog("you are a looser", "looser!")
                for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
                    if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
                        child.Disable()
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
            **if event.Id == -31985:
                pass**
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""   


class Game(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):  # upon game opening
        # I would like the options window to be the first window's parent
        # so I will first set up our options window:
        window = Frame(None, -1, "Good Luck!", GAME_POSITION, GAME_SIZE)
        first_panel = window.panel

        window.write(first_panel, "BULLS AND COWS!", (50, 50), size=(35))
        countX = 500
        countY = 100
        window.create_button(first_panel,"restart!", (50, 400), 100, 100)
        for option in OPTIONS:
            if str(option) == "SEND" or str(option) == "DEL":
                window.disable_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100)
            else:
                window.create_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100)
            countX += 110
            if str(option) == "3" or str(option) == "6" or str(option) == "9":
                countY += 110
                countX = 500



        window.Show(True)
        return True


def main():
    camel = Game()
    camel.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, i created a "restart" button which supposed to restart the game - i mean to play this game again, from the beginning.

In the bold line ( """"""""""" before and after this line) supposed to be the order to restart the game - but i put there 'pass' because i don't know how to make it work.

I tried this:

```
Frame.__init__()
```

But it didn't work..
Can you guys help me with this? thank you very much... :)

Edit:

In accordance with what @Mike Driscoll told me, i tried to make a function that initialize the variables and return the widgets to their first value, and then will call to this function when the user clicks on the "restart!" button..

Here is the function (i put it as one of the methods in the 'Frame' class):

```
def reset(self):
        self.fdf.Clear()
        self.grid.ClearGrid()
        self.count = 0
        self.turnsCounter = 0
        self.numbers = RandomNum()
        self.bulls = 0
        self.cows = 0
        self.counter_of_turns = 0
        self.check = False
        for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
            if child.GetLabel() != "SEND":
                child.Enable()
            else:
                child.Disable()
            if self.count == 0:
                if child.GetLabel() == "DEL":
                    child.Disable()
```

And here is the calling to this function when clicking the button (i put it in the OnButton method):

```
if event.Id == -31985:
                Frame.reset()
```

And it still donesn't do anything.. 
help please :)

Comment: I get a segfault when I try to run your code with wxPython 2.8.12, Python 2.7 on Xubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a reset/restart function that you call when the restart the game. In that function, you just reset the various variables back to zero or whatever their initial state is supposed to be. You can also clear any widgets that you need to in that function.

Comment: Yes i know about this option .. 
But i thought that it gonna make my code inefficient ..
Are you sure there isn't a faster way to restart the variables of my class ?

Comment: Yes, that is the normal way to reset variables. The `__init__` method is only called once when you first create an instance of the class.